# Replacement words

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying write a program that replaces words in a sentence. The input begins with word replacement pairs (original and replacement). The next line of input is the sentence where any word on the original list is replaced. Here is the code I have so far:

```
pair_prompt = input()
sentence_prompt = input()

pair = pair_prompt.split('  ')
my_dict = dict(s.split() for s in pair)
sentence = sentence_prompt.split()

for key, value in my_dict.items():
    if key in sentence:
    index = sentence.index(key)
    sentence[index] = value

print(' '.join(sentence))
```

Input for pair_prompt is: automobile car   manufacturer maker   children kids

Input for sentence_prompt is: The automobile manufacturer recommends car seats for children if the automobile doesn't already have one.

Output is supposed to be: The car maker recommends car seats for kids if the car doesn't already have one.

For some reason the output is: The car maker recommends car seats for kids if the automobile doesn't already have one.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: impossible to tell what your input data is here. instead of `input()` you may want to put something in that others can see, like: `pair_prompt = 'foo bar'`. also, maybe just an artifact of formatting in SO but the line starting with `index =` needs to be indented more.

Comment: `my_dict` is a very obscure variable name to figure out that your intentions are for it.

Comment: Input is right below the code

Comment: Please fix your indentation in your loop as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that your program is only replacing at most one occurrence of the substring in the main string.

For instance, the first `automobile` becomes `car`, but the second one doesn't.

If you want to do this in a clean way, you can leverage the `replace()` method.

```py
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    sentence_prompt = sentence_prompt.replace(key, value)
print(sentence_prompt)
```

If you really want to do it manually by manipulating `sentence`, you can use a nested loop

```py
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    # Use a while instead of the if so that you get all
    # occurrences replaced, not just the first one
    while key in sentence:
       index = sentence.index(key)
       sentence[index] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without looping using regex as `re.sub` can use a function as it's replacement:

```
pair_prompt = input("pair: ")
sentence = input("sentence: ")

pairs = pair_prompt.split()
translation = dict(zip(pairs[::2], pairs[1::2]))

def get_translation(match): 
    s = match[0]
    return translation.get(s, s)

print(re.sub('|'.join(translation), get_translation, sentence, ))
```

---

```
>>> pair: automobile car manufacturer maker children kids
>>> sentence: The automobile manufacturer recommends car seats for children if the automobile doesn't already have one.
The car maker recommends car seats for kids if the car doesn't already have one.
```